# Python: loop index issue

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Idea: I want to replace parts of data1 with newer price data.

Q1: Why are 'laptop' and 'printer' updated, but not 'chair'?

Q2: 'bed' in data2 does not exist for data1. In that case, there can't be an update to data1. I'm just wondering why there is no error like "'bed' has no match in data1"?

```
import pandas as pd

data1 =pd.DataFrame({'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],
        'price': [0, 4, 6, 7, 9]
        })
data2 =pd.DataFrame({'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer','chair','bed'],
        'price': [89,32,34,355]
        })

indi = data2['product_name']

for i in indi:
    temp = data2.loc[data2['product_name'] == '%s'%i,'price']
    data1.loc[data1['product_name'] == '%s'%i,'price'] = temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this: (temp.iloc[0])

```
for i in indi:
    temp = data2.loc[data2['product_name'] == '%s'%i,'price']
    data1.loc[data1['product_name'] == '%s'%i,'price'] = temp.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd like to understand why I have to add ".iloc[0]. I thought temp was a "number".

Comment: Glad it helped you! If you type print(temp), you will see that it is not really a number. It has name and index attached to it.

Comment: Please upvote if this answer was useful.

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder why updating works for the first two entries, but then fails for the last one (when there are some entries in data 2 that are not in data1).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may have something to with non-matching indexes for the `chair` entries. When you loop through `indi`, you get not only the `product_name` from `data` but also its corresponding index. Here's a better way to deal with situations like this:

```
In [53]: data1
Out[53]:
  product_name  price
0       laptop      0
1      printer      4
2       tablet      6
3         desk      7
4        chair      9

In [54]: data2
Out[54]:
  product_name  price
0       laptop     89
1      printer     32
2        chair     34
3          bed    355

In [55]: for row in data2.itertuples():
    ...:     data1.loc[data1['product_name']==row.product_name, 'price'] = row.price
    ...:

In [56]: data1
Out[56]:
  product_name  price
0       laptop     89
1      printer     32
2       tablet      6
3         desk      7
4        chair     34

In [57]: data2
Out[57]:
  product_name  price
0       laptop     89
1      printer     32
2        chair     34
3          bed    355
```